# Cannot reshape array of size x into shape y

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm following a tutorial to create an LSTM neural network using keras.
I have an array of 1270 rows and 26 features.
I split the data like this:

```
train_ind = int(0.8 * X.shape[0])
X_train = X[:train_ind]
X_test = X[train_ind:]
y_train = y[:train_ind]
y_test = y[train_ind:]
```

And i'm trying to reshape it for the lstm using this:

```
num_steps = 4
X_train_shaped = np.reshape(X_train_sc, newshape=(-1, num_steps, 26))
y_train_shaped = np.reshape(y_train_sc, newshape=(-1, num_steps, 26))
assert X_train_shaped.shape[0] == y_train_shaped.shape[0]
```

However, i'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1016 into shape (4,26)
```

Comment: `1016 != 4*26` so you can't reshape.

Answer (score 3):

Well, 4 x 26 = 104, and 1270 isn't divisible by 104, so `np.reshape()` can't choose an integer number of rows (the `-1`) in order to fit that into an array. You need to change either `num_steps` or `num_features` (26) so that `num_steps * num_features` evenly divides 1270. Unfortunately, this is impossible with `num_features = 26`, since 13 does not divide 1270. Your other option is to choose a different number of total rows, say 1040 or 1144, which are both divisible by 104.

So, instead of setting `train_ind = int(0.8 * X.shape[0])`, try `train_id = 1040` or a smaller multiple of 104. Note, however, that your test data will also have to have a nice number of rows in order to reshape it in the same way.

Comment: In writing a tensorflow model, you should never be reshaping the batch axis. That axis is unknown; hence whether or not 1016 is divisible is irrelevant, and could change from batch to batch.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to reshape an array. The shape attribute of a numpy array simply determines how the underlying data is displayed to you and how the data is accessed; changing the shape doesn't actually move any data around.

Likewise, we note that one cannot change the shape to something that is impossible. For example, if an array has size (100,5,6), you can't change this to (100,5,7). In general the axes have to multiple to the correct values. 100*5*6 not equal 100*5*7.

In your case, you sound like you want to work with an LSTM, which would normally mean that you want to simply add an additional axis so that you have input vectors of size 1. A new axis can be added with a None entry in numpy. Something like:

```
X_train = X[:train_ind,:,None] #The axes are Batch, Time, and the Input Vector.
```

Shape should now be (1016,26,1).

Comment: You're right, i'm trying to transform the 2d data into 3d so i can run the lstm but i'm still confused. Can you please further explain how i can achieve that? I cant seem to find the correct numbers for the array to be divisible and reshape.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you try what I wrote above? I added a 1 long axis to the end by placing a None. This makes your dimensions (1016,26,1). Hence, it should now work with a LSTM layer. Such layer will go across your features (26 of them) using the 1-long vector at each feature. The output of each step in the LSTM is specified by you when you create the LSTM. I would need to see more of your code to help further. Do you have minimal working code?